# set-up background image from database with codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

been trying to set-up background-image from database, but still got nothing display except try to make it with "img" tag.

here's the code:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo base_url();?>assets/slide/<?php echo $bn['slide_image']; ?>);"></div>
```

is it possible with just 'css'? hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: what are you getting? Did you debug it? did you open your browser console? Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: Yes it's partially a css problem, you need to set a height and width for a container with only a bg image in it. If there's text in that container this becomes less of an issue.

Comment: i've been try to make a halfside sliding background...sure the path is correct i've tried with img tag and worked...i just want to try to make it as background not img...is my code just correct or can you make another version maybe with js ?

Comment: Look at the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Things you need to make sure are working and the modifications that you might need to make:

I just tried the following example and it is functional.

```
<div class="image "style='background:url("<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/slide/<?php echo '2.jpg'?>");width:200px;height:200px;'></div>
```

- Set a **height** and **width** for the div that needs the background image otherwise the *container won't be visible* at all.
- `<?php echo base_url();>` is missing "?" in the end which should be "?>".
- Make sure you have loaded the url helper in codeignitor **autoload.php** or in your **model for that particular view**.

  `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
- Make sure the *image being used by the echo call* `$bn['slide_image'];` is valid. You can test it out separately.

**Additional tip:** Try and echo the complete url that is being passed to your background inside the container before using it, or check it from your browser's inspector.

Comment: is it must inline too? cause i did it on my extended css like style.css sure i'm add url thing on helper too, and the ?> maybe i forgot to edit the post...

Comment: You can't extend <?php ?> in your style.css, the php tags are only supported in a php file so, making it inline or including the CSS inside your the same php file in <style></style> tags would be preferable.

Comment: sure things lad, i mean the size  "width and height".

Comment: @user3601846 Yeah, you can use the extended css file for that.

Comment: i think i've found the solution, -case closed. see you guys

Comment: @user3601846 What solution was that?